# Does Intel IPP support any GPUs which supports OpenGL?

Tags: opencv, opengl, opencl, intel-ipp

As said [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3226/cvgpuremap-comparatively-slow/?answer=58345#post-id-58345), OpenCV uses IPP which uses GPU:

> It turned out that OpenCV was using IPP and IPP itself can use GPU
>   nowadays.
>
> just in case someone else googles for "opencv gpu slower" and didnt
>   know about the IPP GPU support ;)

Also, I found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimizing-an-augmented-reality-pipeline-using-intel-ipp-asynchronous):

> Optimizing an Augmented Reality Pipeline using **Intel® IPP** Asynchronous
>
> **Using Intel® GPUs** to Optimize the Performance and Power Consumption of
>   Total Immersion's D'Fusion* Augmented Reality Pipeline

And there is no one keyword: *OpenCL, OpenACC, CUDA, nVidia, ...*

There is only one relative to GPU keyword: *OpenGL*

Does this mean that the Intel IPP supports only Intel GPU? Or Intel IPP support any GPU (nVidia GeForce, AMD Radeon) which supports OpenGL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel IPP doesn't support GPUs. It was kind of "preview" product - Intel 8.0 Preview, which was discontinued.

Intel integrated graphics is supported only by OpenCL. Intel IPP is focused on CPUs only.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I was the one of your linked posting...

I didnt try to find out IPP capabilities because it wasnt my project but one of a colleague...

googling talks about "IPP Asynchronous" library and config stuff like

HPP_ACCEL_TYPE_GPU_VIA_DX9 looks like there are options to use OpenCL and DX9 but no warranties from my side that they are supported or that this list is complete...